# Aurdino throws garbage value while transferring from raspberry pi

Tags: python-2.7, audio, serial-port, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3

```
Import serial
ser=serial.Serial(port='/dev/ttyS0',baudrate=9600,
 timeout=0)
 ser.bytesize=8
 ser.parity='N'
 ser.stopbits=1
 ser.write('hello world's)
 ser.close()
```

I want to transfer this string into aurdino from my Raspberry-Pi3 through serial communication but I am receiving garbage values but when m trying to print numeric values it prints fine . Please some one help me out with this problem